# How to dynamically load Word API (office.js) version based on current office version

Tags: office-js, javascript-api-for-office

I am developing word office add-in.I need to load word javascript API based on microsoft version available.
example:-If office version is 2016 i need to load Word API version 1.1
If it is 2019 i need to load Word API 1.2
As of now i am checking whether current office version supporting Word API 1.1 or not.

```
if (!Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', '1.1')) {
            showNotification("Error!", "This version not supported");
            return;
        }
```

But i need to load as per above criteria.
can some one please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load distinct versions of requirement sets like WordApi 1.1. And you don't need to. Each version is a superset of the preceding versions. Use `isSetSupported` to test for WordApi 1.3 (the latest version). If it is supported, your add-in can call any Word API in 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3. If 1.3 is not supported, your code can branch to an alternate experience that only uses APIs in 1.2 or 1.1.

You could also test for 1.2 and, if it is not supported, branch to an alternate experience that uses only 1.1 APIs.

Comment: Hi Rick, is there a way to locally limit the version loaded for testing? I have a functioning add-in that works with WordAPI set 1.3, and now want to see if I can also substite the functions for API set 1.1. But how do I limit the capabilities of my OfficeJS?

Comment: You can't. If you don't want to use the 1.2 or 1.3 APIs, just refrain from calling those APIs in your code. Perhaps what you mean is how do you limit Office into only supporting 1.1. The only way to do that is to install a version of Word that doesn't support 1.2/3. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I was afraid that would be the case. So in order to test code for an older API, I'll have to buy a new license for an outdated version of the product?

Comment: You can test code for an older API on more recent versions of Office. Just refrain from calling the newer APIs.